# IllegalArgumentException on scheduleAtFixedRate Method

Tags: java

```
Runnable runPickWinner = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mPot.pickWinner();
        }
    };
ScheduledExecutorService execPickWinner = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
execPickWinner.scheduleAtFixedRate(runPickWinner, runPickWinnerTime.longValue(), runPickWinnerTime.longValue(), TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at com.tchristofferson.Lottery.runLottery(Lottery.java:223) ~[?:?]
    at com.tchristofferson.Lottery.onEnable(Lottery.java:50) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:271) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-c19c293]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:329) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-c19c293]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:404) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-c19c293]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_11_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:361) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-c19c293]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_11_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:323) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-c19c293]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.MinecraftServer.t(MinecraftServer.java:411) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-c19c293]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.MinecraftServer.l(MinecraftServer.java:372) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-c19c293]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:327) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-c19c293]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:244) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-c19c293]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:521) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-c19c293]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
```

It appears to be an error on the `scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable command, long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit)`, but it makes no sense They are of type Integer, but then I call `longValue()` which should turn them into a long. I have only gotten this to work by hard coding a value in their for example if I use 10L or just 10 it works, but this won't.

Comment: A very brief answer was given to say this was fixed, but it was deleted in the answer review queue. OP, if you can supply an expanded answer, that would be ideal, or failing that a comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Check out the Java implementation of the method you are using i.e. `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate`

```
public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable command,
                                                  long initialDelay,
                                                  long period,
                                                  TimeUnit unit) {
        if (command == null || unit == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        if (period <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        RunnableScheduledFuture<?> t = decorateTask(command,
            new ScheduledFutureTask<Object>(command,
                                            null,
                                            triggerTime(initialDelay, unit),
                                            unit.toNanos(period)));
        delayedExecute(t);
        return t;
    }
```

The exception `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown when `period <= 0`, so basically you are passing `runPickWinnerTime.longValue()` less than 0, i.e. your third argument to the method is less than 0, when it should not be.

When you are hardcoding then you are hard coding correct value, but when you are using `runPickWinnerTime.longValue()` then it is not, so you need to create `runPickWinnerTime` greater than 0, and you should use different object for your `initialDelay` and `period`, I see you are using same and that's causing you unexpected issue.

Comment: What do you mean when you say I should use a different object for period and initialDelay? Am I not supposed to use a long?

Comment: I never said you should not use long, but if you want to pass different values for initial delay and period (your second and third argument) then how would you do it using your same variable `runPickWinnerTime`, and I guess this is what was happening in your case, accidentally you were passing 0 for period as well.